# How to run two different methods with different content views to display data at the same time?

Tags: android, listview

I have two methods that I want to run inside my onlick. The first method is to display a `ListView`. The second method is to get data from a previous `ListView`and put it in the new `ListView`. The aim is to have all these data combined and displayed in the new `ListView` at the same time.

Summary

Display ListView B
Get data from ListView A
Display all Data at the same time

Code

```
btnSave2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PlayerStatsDatabase db = new PlayerStatsDatabase(getApplicationContext());
            db.open();
            db.createStats(txtGoalsScored.getText().toString(),  txtMinutesPlayed.getText().toString(),txtSubstituteIn.getText().toString(),txtSubstituteOut.getText().toString(), checkText.toString());
            db.close();
            displayListView();
            dipsplayPlayerName();



        }
    });
 }
private void displayListView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //playerTitle.setText (PlayerNameText);
Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllStats();
    setContentView(R.layout.playerstats);
      // The desired columns to be bound
      String[] columns = new String[] {
        PlayerStatsDatabase.KEY_SCORE,
        PlayerStatsDatabase.KEY_MINUTES,
        PlayerStatsDatabase.KEY_SUBIN,
        PlayerStatsDatabase.KEY_SUBOUT,
        PlayerStatsDatabase.KEY_BOOKING,

      };

      // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
      int[] to = new int[] { 
        R.id.pGoals,
        R.id.pMinutes,
        R.id.pSubIn,
        R.id.pSubOut,
        R.id.pBook,
      };

      // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data 
      //as well as the layout information
      statsAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        this, R.layout.statslist, 
        cursor, 
        columns, 
        to
        );

      ListView list= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
      // Assign adapter to ListView
      list.setAdapter(statsAdapter);

      statsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
private void dipsplayPlayerName() {
    setContentView (R.layout.statslist);
     playerTitle = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textTitle);
     playerTitle.setText (PlayerData);
     playerNumber = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.pNumber);
     playerNumber.setText (playerNumberStr);
     playerPosition = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.pPosition);
     playerPosition.setText (playerPositionStr);
     playerTeam = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.pTeam);
     playerTeam.setText (playerTeamStr);
}
}
```

The problem is they both wont work at the same time. The one that gets called first is the only one that works.

How would I fix this?

Comment: do you get any errors?, if you do then post logcat trace

Comment: No I do not get any errors.